# laravel 5.3 x-editable table bulk is updating, single row in-line is not - Internal server error 500

Tags: laravel-5.3, x-editable

I have implemented this example by Papadupa **verbatum** that illustrates bulk editing and row editing (column in line and column pop-up):
 https://gist.github.com/pupadupa/4b8e8a9a3a466720bad8

The bulk updating works just fine, but the inline row field editing does not, and reports an internal server error (500):
 jquery.js:8625  localhost:8000/test/update/1 500 (Internal Server Error)

[x-editable table row edit error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv9cM.jpg)

Here is papadupa's implementation:

Test Table - you do need to add a couple of rows to the test table after the table is created so there are updatable rows available:

```
`class CreateTestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->float('value')->nullable();
            $table->date('date')->nullable();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tests');
    }
}`
```

The Controller:

```
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Test;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $test = Test::select()
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->get()
        ;

        // $test_columns = Schema::getColumnListing('tests');
        $test_model = new Test();
        $fillable_columns = $test_model->getFillable();
        foreach ($fillable_columns as $key => $value) {
            $test_columns[$value] = $value;
        }
        return view('test.index',[
            'test'=>$test,
            'test_columns'=>$test_columns,
        ]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $test = Test::find($id);
        $column_name = Input::get('name');
        $column_value = Input::get('value');

        if( Input::has('name') && Input::has('value')) {
            $test = Test::select()
                ->where('id', '=', $id)
                ->update([$column_name => $column_value]);
            return response()->json([ 'code'=>200], 200);
        }

        return response()->json([ 'error'=> 400, 'message'=> 'Not enought params' ], 400);
    }



    public function bulk_update(Request $request)
    {
        if (Input::has('ids_to_edit') && Input::has('bulk_name') && Input::has('bulk_value')) {
            $ids = Input::get('ids_to_edit');
            $bulk_name = Input::get('bulk_name');
            $bulk_value = Input::get('bulk_value');
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $test = Test::select()
                    ->where('id', '=', $id)
                    ->update([$bulk_name => $bulk_value]);
            }
            // return Redirect::route('client/leads')->with('message', $message);
            $message = "Done";
        } else {
            $message = "Error. Empty or Wrong data provided.";
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(array('message' => $message))->withInput();
        }
        return Redirect::back()->with('message', $message);
    }

}`
```

The Routes:

```
    `
       Route::get('test', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);
        Route::post('test/update/{id}', ['as' => 'test/update', 'uses' => 'TestController@update']);
        Route::post('test/bulk_update', ['as' => 'test/bulk_update', 'uses' => 'TestController@bulk_update']);
    `
```

The /test/index.blade.php file:

```
`@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        Oops! We have some erros
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if(Session::has('message'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {!!Session::get('message')!!}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <h2>Bulk edit</h2>
                {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TestController@bulk_update', 'method' => "POST", "class"=>"form-inline"]) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lead_status">For selected rows change filed </label>
                    {!! Form::select('bulk_name', $test_columns, [], ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lead_status">equal to</label>
                    {!! Form::text('bulk_value', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                <hr>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    @foreach($test as $t)
                        <tr>
                            <td><td width="10px"><input type="checkbox" name="ids_to_edit[]" value="{{$t->id}}" /></td></td>
                            <td>{{$t->id}}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="testEdit"
                                   data-type="text" data-column="name"
                                   data-url="{{route('test/update', ['id'=>$t->id])}}"
                                   data-pk="{{$t->id}}" data-title="change" data-name="name">{{$t->name}}</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="testEdit"
                                   data-type="text" data-column="value"
                                   data-url="{{route('test/update', ['id'=>$t->id])}}"
                                   data-pk="{{$t->id}}" data-title="change" data-name="value">{{$t->value}}</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="testEdit"
                                   data-type="text" data-column="date"
                                   data-url="{{route('test/update', ['id'=>$t->id])}}" data-pk="{{$t->id}}" data-title="change" data-name="date">{{$t->date}}</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
                {!! Form::close() !!}


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.testEdit').editable({
                params: function(params) {
                    // add additional params from data-attributes of trigger element
                    params.name = $(this).editable().data('name');
                    return params;
                },
                error: function(response, newValue) {
                    if(response.status === 500) {
                        return 'Server error. Check entered data.';
                    } else {
                        return response.responseText;
                        // return "Error.";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection`
```

and the app.blade file:

```
`!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>xEditable and laravel 5. Inline and bulk editing examples.</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
`
```

I am running Laravel 5.3 and I do not know which laravel version pupadupa used.  My original objective is to be able to implement laravel 5.3 inline table editing using eloquent Model.  X-editable seems to be a perfect fit, if I can just get it to work.

Papadupa's example is terrific because it simplifies the coding to edit any xeditable column in a table row. I don't believe this is an x-crsf issue because the 'bulk_update' function works for the the same table and form using the script for x-editable. It appears the single row update is not updating the database so there is no valid response coming back

Comment: You need to look at what your server respond. You can see it like in your secreen shot. You should click "Network" tab and select your request and look your server response in "Response" tab. If you can not realize the problem so you should edit your question with this response.

Comment: The first line in my question states "reports an internal server error (500)", but I have edited my question with the literal message.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!**
It **was** a x-csrf issue:

I added this to the view (app.blade.php):

```
 ` <div id="_token" class="hidden" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></div>`
```

and added another param to the script section:

```
 `params._token = $("#_token").data("token");`
```

Interesting that the bulk_update function worked without this x-csrf inclusion.  I remain curious as to why . . .

Comment: I could be wrong but I would imagine the reason you're bulk upload worked is because `Form::open()` automatically included the `csrf_field` for you.